# Parse a String into an Array with New Line Chain by Regex without any Remove in PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I need to parse this string:

```
$str = "\n\n\nABC\n\nDEF\nGHI\n\n\nJKL" ;
```

into this array:

```
$arr = [
    "\n\n\n",
    "ABC\n",
    "\n",
    "DEF\n",
    "GHI\n",
    "\n\n",
    "JKL"
] ;
```

I tried many combinations, but no luck:

```
$arr = preg_match_all("/[^\n]+[\n]+/",$str,$out) ;
```

What Regex can handle that?

Comment: Why the three leading newlines are kept together but the three inner newlines come into separate strings in the posted example? What is the split rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern does the job:

```
preg_match_all('~\n+|.+\n?~', $str, $matches);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/qZt9Y)

As an aside, `preg_match_all` returns the number of matches or `false`, the matches are stored in the third parameter.

Comment: "/[^\n]+|[\n]+/" also works very well, thank you very much!

Comment: You are right, thats my hurriedness :), thank you again!!